# Set WordPress user email instead of billing email as default value for WooCommerce checkout field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

What I am trying to do is change the checkout fields so that if a user is logged in they can't edit their billing email field.

This code below works great however ideally I want to remove the situation where users are able to have 2 email address in the first place and set the value of `$address_fields['billing']['billing_email']` to be the users email address from their account.

I've tried adding

```
'value' => $current_user->user_email
```

and

```
'default' => $current_user->user_email
```

to the array however this appears to do nothing.

So:

1. Firstly, how can I set a value for this form and prevent it from being changed.
2. Secondly, is `$current_user->user_email` the correct way to get the users account (contact) email and not the billing email from their account.

```js
function custom_checkout_fields( $address_fields ) {
    
    
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        unset( $address_fields['billing']['billing_email'] );
        unset( $address_fields['billing']['billing_em_ver'] );
    
    $address_fields['billing']['billing_email'] = [
            'label' => 'Email address',
            'required'  => false,
            'description'   =>  '<i><a href="/shop/my-account/customer-logout/">to change this please click here logout and login/register as another user</a> or <a href="/shop/my-account/edit-account/">click here to modify the address on your account</a></i>',
            'custom_attributes' => [
                'disabled' => 'disabled',
            ]
        ];
    
    
    
        return $address_fields;
    } else{
    return $address_fields;
    }
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_checkout_fields' ,20, 1 );
```

Comment: The inconsistencies in how this is handled out of the box are pretty bonkers. Updating the billing email does not change the account email. Updating the account email updates the billing email but does not give you an opportunity to change any subscription billing emails. Updating billing email gives you an option to update all subscription emails or not, indicating that subscription billing emails should be individually editable, but they are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, go to `/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout`, copy the `form-billing.php` template file found in that folder and paste it in `yourTheme/woocommerce/checkout/`.

Secondly, prevent WooCommerce from auto-filling the email address field by editing the copied `form-billing.php` template file and changing the following snippet:

```
    <div class="woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper">
      <?php
      $fields = $checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'billing' );

      foreach ( $fields as $key => $field ) {
        woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) );
      }
      ?>
    </div>
```

To this:

```
    <div class="woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper">
      <?php
      $fields = $checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'billing' );

      foreach ( $fields as $key => $field ) {
        if ( 'billing_email' != $key ) {
            woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) );
        } else {
            woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field );
        }
      }
      ?>
    </div>
```

Thirdly, inject the WordPress email to the field, make it immutable and add your custom description by adding the following to your theme's `functions.php` file:

```js
function shillongtitude_billing_email_field($fields) {
  
  if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    //set the user email as the email field value
    $fields['billing']['billing_email']['default'] = $current_user->user_email;
    
    //set the description
    $fields['billing']['billing_email']['description'] = '<i><a href="/shop/my-account/customer-logout/">to change this please click here logout and login/register as another user</a> or <a href="/shop/my-account/edit-account/">click here to modify the address on your account</a></i>';
    
    // set attributes
    $fields['billing']['billing_email']['custom_attributes'] = array( 'readonly'=>'readonly', 'label' => 'Email address', 'required' => false );
            
    return $fields;
  } else {
    return $fields;
  }
}
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'shillongtitude_billing_email_field');
```

Comment: close but no cigar, this pulls in the "billing email address" and not the users account email address they log in with. It's the same issue I keep bumping into

Comment: @HenryAspden The billing email of my test account is the same as the WordPress email of that same account lol The above still returns the billing email indeed. Let me fiddle around with the above code a lil bit more.

Comment: I ran into the exact same issue with mine too thought i'd cracked it then realised my emails were matching haha

Comment: @HenryAspden So I found out that the above function is retrieving the WordPress email as required. However, because WooCommerce autopopulates the Billing info in the Checkout page, the email field ended up (being overwritten maybe?) with the billing email instead. Check the updated answer for a workaround to this.

Comment: Note that the confusing second billing email field is also available in the address change fields in the user dashboard: /my-account/edit-address/billing/

Answer (score 0):

**Use if you need changing user details while submitting new woo order**

---

This function will compare checkout fields:

> billing_first_name - billing_last_name - billing_email

with personal account fields:

> first_name - last_name - display_name

and will update in case of discrepancy while submitting new order.

```
add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'sync_woocommerce_email', 10, 2) ;
    function sync_woocommerce_email( $order_id ) {
        $current_user   = wp_get_current_user();
        $user_cname     = $current_user->display_name;
        $user_fname     = $current_user->first_name;
        $user_lname     = $current_user->last_name;
        $user_fullname  = $user_fname.' '.$user_lname;
        $bill_fname     = $current_user->billing_first_name;
        $bill_lname     = $current_user->billing_last_name;
        $bill_fullname  = $bill_fname.' '.$bill_lname;
        
        if ($current_user->user_email != $current_user->billing_email) {
            wp_update_user( array ( 'ID' => $current_user->ID, 'user_email' => $current_user->billing_email ) ) ;
        }
        if ($current_user->display_name != $bill_fullname) {
            wp_update_user( array ( 'ID' => $current_user->ID, 'display_name' => $bill_fullname ) ) ;
        }
         
    }
```